# Prove $ 5(a^4+b^4+c^4)+9≥8(a^3+b^3+c^3) $ if $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove that:
$$
5(a^4+b^4+c^4)+9≥8(a^3+b^3+c^3)
$$
I tried to homogenize the inequality to get:
$$
5(a^4+b^4+c^4)+(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2≥\frac{8}{\sqrt3}(a^3+b^3+c^3)\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)}
$$
I hoped that one don't needs the condition anymore to prove this, but I couldn't get any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it as follows:

The inequality is equivalent to:
$$
\sum_{cyc}5a^4-8a^3+3a^2≥0\iff\sum_{cyc}5a^2\left(\left(a-\frac{4}{5}\right)^2-\frac{1}{25}\right)≥0\iff\sum_{cyc}a^2\left(\left(5a-4\right)^2-1\right)≥0\iff\\
\sum_{cyc}a^2(5a-4)^2≥3\iff\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}a^2(5a-4)^2}≥1
$$
Now, by AM-QM:
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}a^2(5a-4)^2}≥\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}a(5a-4)=5-4\frac{a+b+c}{3}≥5-4\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}=1
$$
And we're done.

Comment: Does AM QM and those other inequalities work for negative reals too?

Comment: For most of the other inequalities  no, but AM QM is special: if the numbers are negative, the QM remains invariant while the AM only gets smaller.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

It is enough to show $f(x)=5x^4+3-8x^3+2(x^2-1)=(x-1)^2(5x^2+2x+1)\ge0$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM:
$$\begin{aligned}a^4+a^4+a^4+a^4+a^4+a^2+a^2+1&\ge 8\sqrt[8]{a^{4\times 5}a^{2\times 2}}\\&=8\sqrt[8]{a^{24}}\\&=8|a^3|\ge8a^3.\end{aligned}$$
Similarly for $b$ and $c$ and add them up.